# Adding multiple headers while calling REST api via Jersey clients

Tags: java, rest, jersey, http-headers, jersey-client

I am trying to add multiple header. But failed miserably so far. I had tried lots of code tweaking but failed. Can someone help me fix the code or at least tell me what's wrong ?

Header mapping code:

```
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

    headers.put("authorization", authToken);
    headers.put("API-Version", apiVersion);
    headers.put("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

actual calling code:

```
    String serviceUrl = serviceHostUrl;
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(serviceUrl).path(path);

    WebResource.Builder builder = webResource.getRequestBuilder();
    if(headers != null && !headers.isEmpty()) {
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            builder.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    ClientResponse response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

**UPDATE**

if in second snippet I use below code instead of setting headers in loop, it works fine. That's really weird.

```
    builder.header("authorization", "Basic SDFSFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDF");
    builder.header("API-Version", "5.2");
    builder.header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: "But failed miserably so far.". What problem/error are you getting?

Comment: I am trying to add more than one header to the POST call, but while calling one one header (always the last one in map) is attached with the call instead of three.

Comment: The code looks good. Add some logging statements in the for loop for `headers` to see if the entries added in headers are still maintained.

Comment: only the last entry in the loop is added.

Comment: What I mean is, in the first code-snippet you're adding entries to `headers`. Could you add logging statements in the loop in second code-snippet and show us the output to ensure that all the entries added in first snippet are still maintained?

Comment: Yes they are maintained :) the loop runs three time but only the last header gets persisted once the loop in 2nd snippet finishes. It's kind of over-riding the header

Comment: Furthermore, if I remove the loop in second snippet that are setting the headers like below. The call works fine.

{code}
        builder.header("authorization", "Basic 132342sdf");
        builder.header("API-Version", "5.2");
        builder.header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
{code}

Comment: Not sure if this will solve it. But you can try. Instead of `builder = builder.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());` do just `builder.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());`. Remove the `builder = ` part.

Comment: did this already, no luck :(

Comment: If the code is exactly what you have shown here then I don't see any problem. Perhaps it is somewhere else. Only advice I can give you now is try debugging tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124117/discussion-between-maningreen-and-balkrishna-rawool).

Comment: @ManinGreen did you get the right answer for your problem? Please share it!

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/jersey-webresource-header-dont

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is, type of MAP that you are trying to access.

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

The WebSource builder accepts header(String,Object). So Try with changing the map type.

Answer (score 0):

The header method does change the builder object. It creates a new object and the existing builder is not affected.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
  builder = builder.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Basic auth is like: Authorization  = "Authorization" ":" credentials

an example

```
byte[] loginBytes = ("1" + ":" + "1").getBytes();
StringBuilder authString = new StringBuilder().append("Basic ")
                .append(Base64.encodeToString(loginBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP));

_headers.put("Authorization", authString );
```

Comment: my question is not related to authorization. please re-read the question.

Comment: this don't answers the question.